# Selenium webdriver does not see that site is not safe

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to check if site is safe/does not have any google warnings with selenium webdriver:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()


options.headless = True
options.add_experimental_option( "prefs", {'safebrowsing.enabled':'true'})
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", options=options)

driver.get("https://example.com/")
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```

i know that my scriptwill output title of site but is there any way to get info if site is safe?
When i enter via my chrome browser on any site that is not safe i can see that there is phishing warning, but when i enter via webdriver it says nothing about phishing, 0 warnings, nothing.
Below screenshot of warning im talking about:
[image: google warning]

All in all my main goal is to get information is site is safe or not via selenium. Is there is any way to do it without using google api?

thanks
v

Comment: You can't click on such elements as "warning boxes" alerts and pages like this with selenium-webdriver, i would suggest you to find a way to trust the site in order to display it.

Comment: Well i thought about it for a while, and now im open to python without selenium. Just to get info if site is malicious or not. Yet the alert seems to be in shadow dom(?). And after getting any data from page its like ignoring google alert ;/